# Changing Filenames on a NAS with Python

Tags: python, filenames

I have a python script that works perfectly to find and replace specified characters or phrases with other information (in most cases I am just removing characters) when the location of the folder to scan is on the local laptop.

When trying to change its path to a folder on my NAS, there is no update to the filename while pycharm returns a successful code.

If possible, I'd like to avoid copy GBs worth of data to my laptop to modify and then push it back to the NAS.

Below is the script contents:

```
import os

paths = (os.path.join(root, filename)
        for root, _, filenames in os.walk('afp://NAS-SYN._afpovertcp._tcp.local/Home/Documents/Finances')
        for filename in filenames)

# The keys of the dictionary are the values to replace, each corresponding
# item is the string to replace it with
replacements = {'&': '',
                'Hello.Everyone.':'Hello Everyone - '}


for path in paths:
    # Copy the path name to apply changes (if any) to
    newname = path
    # Loop over the dictionary elements, applying the replacements
    for k, v in replacements.items():
        newname = newname.replace(k, v)
    if newname != path:
        os.rename(path, newname)
```

Comment: seriously had the same problem but can you try shutil ? https://docs.python.org/2/library/shutil.html

Comment: @ChetanVasudevan - not sure there is an application for that with this based on reviewing the link.  I'm a noob with python so I could be offbase.